# How do you access S3 Bucket protected by an IAM role using the Java SDK?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-eks

I have a S3 Bucket setup in AWS which is proteced by an IAM Role. 
I am writing an application which should access that bucket. The application deployed to an EKS cluster and gets the role via a Service Account setting (following the IRSA concept). This works fine so far.

But for testing/developing I want to be able to run the application locally as well. So how do I assign the IAM role to my application when running locally?

When running in EKS the permissions are handled by the cluster, so from the Java code I just need to create a default S3 client and then I am able to put objects:

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
s3Client.putObject(bucketName, key, data);
```

This will of course not work out of the box locally.

I have an AWS Profile defined in my config file:

```
[profile test]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::...
source_profile = default
region = eu-central-1

### MFA Authenticated
[default]
region = eu-central-1
```

When logged in I am able to see the bucket from my console using:

```
aws s3api list-objects --bucket <bucketname> --profile test
```

I connected my profile to the application by providing the environment variables:

```
AWS_PROFILE=test
AWS_REGION=eu-central-1
```

I tried with `AWS_PROFILE="profile test"` as well.

When running my code I get

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
Requests specifying Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed keys require AWS Signature Version 4.
(Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidArgument;
```

I am using Java SDK 1.11.738 and made sure in maven's pom.xml that sdk-s3, sdk-core and sdk-kms all have the same version:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.738</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmespath-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.738</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kms</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.738</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmespath-java</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.738</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're having separate issues.

The error you're getting is coming from the fact that you haven't specified the Signature Version.

```
System.setProperty(SDKGlobalConfiguration.ENABLE_S3_SIGV4_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "true");
```

[Further reading](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingAWSSDK.html).

Secondly, as for the role, the role will need to be set on the EKS instance.

Comment: Providing the Property -Dcom.amazonaws.services.s3.enforceV4="true" has no effect. Still the same error.
When running the application in EKS the role is assigned to the application's Service-Account. This works well. My question is about running the application locally, not in EKS.

Comment: Ah my mistake, missed the locally part. Haven't done things that way, but I would try and use Keys as per the docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-crypto-kms.html

Comment: Good hint, at least now I get a different error. s3Client is now AmazonS3Encryption s3Client =
        AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
            .standard()
            .withEncryptionMaterials(new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider(
                "arn:aws:kms:eu-central-1:..."))
        .build();
Also I added variables for AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_SESSION_TOKEN. The freshly regenerated MFA token seems to be problematic as I now receive "The security token included in the request is invalid (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException"

Answer (score 0):

You need to get temporary values for below by using your arn.

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN

and after that add these to your service's environment variable or pass them as environment variables while launching the service locally.